# Multiple mkl packages installed in anaconda

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, intel-mkl

I've just observed that there are tree different version of `mkl` package installed on my computer.

```
du -sh */
417M    mkl-2017.0.1-0/
407M    mkl-2017.0.3-0/
557M    mkl-2018.0.1-hfbd8650_4/
526M    mkl-2018.0.2-1/
```

I know that `mkl` package included in numpy and pandas install but I didn't expect it influence the binary size so dramatically.

Can I delete any of this package or somehow reduce it size?

Answer (score 5):

The command `conda clean --all` is supposed to only remove the packages and cache you don't use. You can run it to decrease the size conda packages take on your computer, or use `conda clean --all --dry-run` just to see which packages would end up being uninstalled if you run the clean command.